# What does "keep the lock clear" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-meaning

I'm listening to [this](http://www.se-radio.net/2016/08/se-radio-episode-265-pat-kua-on-becoming-a-tech-lead/) podcast (there's also the transcript below the page) and during it the host says:

> Both me and Pat work for software, so that’s why I attended one of his
>   trainings, just to keep the lock clear.

I look around a bit but I can't understand the meaning of "keep the lock clear". What does this phrase mean here?

Comment: You will to ask the person who said the sentence. His English is not good. For instance, he asks *Pat, is there anything more you would like to say **to** yourself?* when he should have asked *Pat, is there anything more you would like to say **about** yourself?*

Comment: "Keep the lock clear" doesn't look like an idiomatic phrase.  My first guess was that it was a metaphor relating to "locks" in the water navigation sense:  A device for raising or lowering water levels to allow ships through a canal.

Comment: In my experience of  American and, I think, British English, we also don't  use *training* as a count noun, so we wouldn't say his *"Pat has also been involved in giving **trainings** on technical leadership..."* but something like *training seminars*. We also don't *work **for** software*.

Comment: @Clare you're right. He's not a native English speaker. I'm starting to think this may be a phrase from another language that's been translated to English in a bad way.

Comment: "Clearing a lock" is manipulating it so that it's in a "neutral" position, generally unlocked.  Exactly what this means in the above context is unclear, however.

Comment: "the lock clear" in German might be something like "das schloss klar" which (listening to that section) could be some oddly phonetic version of "disclosure" which he then translated partially. Tortured narrative, but sometimes people use mnemonics? (As Clare rightly points out, this is a German speaker with an accent with admirable but flawed English)

Comment: Could the word he's saying actually be "link"?  He's trying to clarify that the two have a work connection.  (The podcast link works for me only as text--no audio.)

Comment: @Xanne I don't know where it's gone but here's the [link](http://traffic.libsyn.com/seradio/SE-Radio-Episode-265-Pat-Kua-on-Becoming-a-Tech-Lead.mp3?_=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Perfect. Both me and Pat work for software, so that’s why I attended one of his trainings, just to keep the lock clear. The very first question that comes into mind when talking about becoming a tech lead is what is the role of a technical lead?...

The speaker is not (correctly) speaking British or American English and has several inconsistencies with those major Englishes. For example, native speakers  don't use *trainings* as a count noun, and we wouldn't ask someone, in this context *"Pat, is there anything more you would like to say **to** yourself?"* but *...**about** yourself*. We also don't *work for software*, but something like *in software*.

Anyway, the transcription is not perfect and the speaker is actually  saying

> ... *work for ThoughtWorks*

Based on the context, he probably means

> to clear the air

which in this context would mean

> remove any doubts

See definition 2 in [the free dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/clear+the+air) 
A "lock" (in addition to the lock on your door) is

> 4 [COUNTABLE] a place on a river or canal with a set of gates which open and close to allow boats in. The water can then be moved to a lower or higher level.

([MacMillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/lock_2))

Locks will only work properly if they are kept clear of  branches and other possible obstructions.

But if he is using "Keep the lock clear" in this way, it's the first and only time I've heard it. It's not an everyday metaphor, like "clear the air," which is.

Perhaps it's a saying  borrowed from his native language, which seems to be German. See  [his blog](http://blog.jthoenes.net).

In addition, a native speaker of English would rarely use such a noticeable gap between the word *lock* and *clear*. We would not normally bother to distinctly separate the ending *-ck* of *lock* and the beginning *k- sound* of *clear*.

Or it's possible the speaker means  *link* instead of *lock*. (Keep the link clear.)